# SQL query Help about Datetime type

Tags: java, sql

I want to write a time check. That is 1 customer can't deposit more than 5 times 1 days. I just wrote this to check:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID 
FROM TRANSACTIONS 
WHERE (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())) BETWEEN ((SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE()))-24) AND (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())) 
AND METHODID = 1 
AND CUSTOMERID = 8
```

To count customer and check if >5 return false. But i think it's wrong. Anyone help me the query about hour and date ( Column Date is `DATETIME` type)

[Here the image of my table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqGuA.jpg)

Comment: your dbms name please

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You have a customer ID and wanna check the number of transaction in a day of that customer and allow it for the transaction if count is less than 5.            So try the following query.(Query will return "true" if transactions<5 else "false").

```
select case when count(*) < 5 then 'True' else 'False' end  from [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] 
where CUSTOMERID = 8
and cast([YOUR_DATE_COLUMN_NAME] as date)=cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregate function `count`, `group by` clause and `case when` for checking

If your dbms is Mysql then below query will help you

```
select customerid,date(date) as date_of_month,
  case when count(transactionid)>5 then 'false' else 'True'
  from TRANSACTIONS        
  group by customerid,date(date)
```

If your dbms is mssql server

```
select customerid,convert(date,[date]) as date_of_month,  
case when count(transactionid)>5 then 'false' else 'True' 
from   TRANSACTIONS            
group by customerid,convert(date,[date])
```

Comment: @Bao Tran Hoai does it helps?